# How can I send an image of a live video through a web socket and store it in a React state variable?

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, getusermedia, react-state-management

I'm using **React** and **socket.io** to build a chat room where people can live stream video.

I have a video player with a live stream that I want to pass through socket.io. When the stream is passed from the client to the server and back to the client, I want to store it in a state variable as an item in an array so I can display all live streams to a user.

Right now I am just trying to draw an image of the stream on a `<canvas>` and emit that.

*I define each stream by the current user streaming, using their `user.username`.*

**Stream.js**

```
function Stream(props) {

    const refVideo = useRef();
    const refCanvas = useRef();

    const [streams, setStreams] = useState([]);

    function startStream() {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            video: true,
            audio: true
        }).then((stream) => {
            // set source of video to stream
            refVideo.current.srcObject = stream;

            // define canvas context
            const context = refCanvas.current.getContext('2d');

            // emit canvas as data url every 100 milliseconds
            const interval = setInterval(() => {
                // draw image
                context.drawImage(refVideo.current, 0, 0, context.width, context.height);

                // define stream by username
                const streamObj = {
                    image: refCanvas.current.toDataURL('image/jpeg'),
                    username: props.user.username,
                };

                // send stream to server
                socket.emit('stream', streamObj);
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        // when stream is received from server
        socket.on('stream', function(data) {

            // find stream by username
            const foundStream = streams.find((stream) => {
                return stream.username === data.username;
            });

            // ONLY if stream was not found, add it to state
            if(!foundStream) {
                setStreams((streams) => [...streams, data]);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <video ref={refVideo} />
        <canvas ref={refCanvas} />
    );
}
```

**server.js**

```
socket.on('stream', function(data) {
  // send stream back to room
  io.to(room).emit('stream', data);
});
```

My stream displays in the `<video>` and the object is emitted through the socket to the server and back to the client but for some reason, my stream is being added to my `streams` state array *every* time (every 100ms interval).

I check if the stream is already in the array using `foundStream`, so I'm not sure why that is happening. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. emit sent to all, including the sender, you should use broadcast.emit to send to all except the sender itself.